# installing pygame module for python 2.7.5 on terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pygame

i have already downloaded 32 bit pygame module on my mac osx 10.9.1 but i have no idea how to install it . I have tried different things but i am not able to get it working in terminal. I was able to easily download PIL package using terminal.
Can Someone please give me all the steps for installing pygame?

Comment: http://www.pygame.org/install.html

Answer (score 0):

Binary packages are available from http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml - just run the downloaded `.dmg`.

If you've downloaded a source package, extract it and run `python setup.py install` inside the folder.

Otherwise you might be able to:

```
easy_install pygame
```

or

```
pip install pygame
```

Each of these might need `sudo` to run if you are installing into the system python.

If you are using a package manager you might use

```
port install py-game
```

or

```
fink install pygame
```

or possibly

```
brew install pygame
```