# Errors when importing SimpleCV in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed SimpleCV to play with some image processing stuff in python.I installed it using

```
pip install SimpleCV
```

Then I tried to import it in my BLANK program but got following error

```
 print 'unit test'
                    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

I thought that may be SimpleCV did not install properly so I again did

```
pip install SimpleCV
```

But the following message came

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): SimpleCV in c:\users\naseer786\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

My current working directory is

```
C:\\Users\\Naseer786\\Documents\\Python Scripts
```

Can some body help me what is the solution to get out of this mess?

Comment: Looks like you're using Python 2 syntax, but a Python3 interpreter. Use Python 3 syntax instead. For print, that would be `print('unit test')`.

Comment: @Evert There is not yet single line of code in my file.

Comment: Sadly, it appears that simpleCV has not yet been ported to Python 3. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728151/simplecv-not-working-python3-4-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-prin

Comment: @Evert does that mean nothing can be done right now?

Comment: You may switch to Py2.x...

Comment: Switch to Python 2, or do a lot of hard work and convert simpleCV to Python 3...